# Click on multiple elements using selenium on Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, bots

I would like to create a bot which will retweet all tweet load on an account. 
First I try to use this method:

```
rt = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@data-testid='retweet']")

for i in rt:

        time.sleep(1)
        i.click()

        """Confirm the retweet"""
        time.sleep(1)
        self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@data-testid='retweetConfirm']").click()
```

But it didn't work, I wasn't able to wait enought before clicking, even with a high time.sleep().
So instead, I try this:

```
for i in rt:

    z=WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@data-testid='retweet']")))
    z.click()

    #Confirm the retweet
    b=WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@data-testid='retweetConfirm']")))
    b.click()
```

Unfortunately this code will only retweet the first tweet. I should modify something in EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.Xpath,"//*[@data-testid='retweet'])) (and in the second EC.element_to_be_clickable) to go to the next tweet for each iteration but I don't know what.

Does anybody know a way to iterate through all my tweets with this method (or another)? I have been thinking about getting the absolute path of all my element in "rt" but I don't know if I can do this using only Selenium. I could also use Twitter API but I want to be able to create a bot on others websites.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I think I have found a solution to my issue.
For each click, I try to catch the exception "ElementClickInterceptedException" when it happens; otherwise I click on my retweet.

So it gaves something like that:

```
  for i in rt:

        first_clique=False
        while first_clique==False:
            try:
                i.click()
            except ElementClickInterceptedException:
                pass
            else:
                first_clique= True
```